# What association should be used for "tags" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

AngelList.co has an API that returns data about its companies, jobs, and people.

Each company, job, and person record can have several "tags" with information like "skill", "location", "role", "market", etc.

How would these "tags" be modeled in Rails?

**Example JSON for a Company:**

```
{
  "id": 6702,
  "name": "AngelList",
  "angellist_url": "http://localhost:3000/angellist",
  "markets": [
    {
      "id": 448,
      "tag_type": "MarketTag",
      "name": "startups",
      "display_name": "Startups",
      "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/startups-1"
    },
    {
      "id": 856,
      "tag_type": "MarketTag",
      "name": "venture capital",
      "display_name": "Venture Capital",
      "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/venture-capital"
    }
  ],
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1692,
      "tag_type": "LocationTag",
      "name": "san francisco",
      "display_name": "San Francisco",
      "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/san-francisco"
    }
  ],
  "status": {
    "message": "You're insane if you don't follow the AngelList Twitter...",
    "created_at": "2011-08-07T00:56:25Z"
  },
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "thumb": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../009cff275fb96709c915c4d4-thumb.jpg",
      "original": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../009cff275fb96709c915c4d4-original.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Example JSON for a Job:**

```
{
  "id": 97,
  "title": "Venture Hacker",
  "created_at": "2011-12-05T21:05:43Z",
  "updated_at": "2012-02-13T03:40:17Z",
  "equity_cliff": 1.0,
  "equity_min": 0.25,
  "equity_max": 0.25,
  "equity_vest": 4.0,
  "salary_min": 100000,
  "salary_max": 100000,
  "job_type": "full-time",
  "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/angellist/jobs/97",
  "startup": {
    "id": 6702,
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "AngelList",
    "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/angellist",
    "logo_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/6702-...",
    "thumb_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/6702-...",
    "product_desc": "AngelList is an online community that helps startups...",
    "high_concept": "Platform for startups",
    "follower_count": 876,
    "company_url": "http://angel.co"
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 14766,
      "tag_type": "SkillTag",
      "name": "software engineering",
      "display_name": "Software Engineering",
      "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/software-engineering"
    },
    {
      "id": 1692,
      "tag_type": "LocationTag",
      "name": "san francisco",
      "display_name": "San Francisco",
      "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/san-francisco"
    },
    {
      "id": 14726,
      "tag_type": "RoleTag",
      "name": "developer",
      "display_name": "Developer",
      "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/developer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you syncing the data from AngelList or just want to create something similar?

Comment: This road has been paved before. Check out acts-as-taggable-on or other such gems: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/tree/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a polymorphic association to me:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, as: :taggable
end

class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.integer :taggable_id
      t.string :taggable_type
      t.string :tag_type
      t.string :name
      t.string :display_name
      t.string :angellist_url  
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works. But this is just a `has_many` and I think a HABTM would be more appropriate.

Comment: @john - the issue here is that you would have multiple entries for the tag "United States", since many companies and people would have that tag.